# Best swing interface for event notification

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, interface

I'm coding a java swing component (an expanding panel) and I want to allow (in memory/jmv) subscriptions to the expand event or maybe even the collapse events. Is there a current recommended practice already for this?

If the section is collapsed only the header icon and header title will be visible. When a user clicks on the image or header the section content will appear. When expanded, clicking on the header icon or header will collapse and hide the section content.

in collapsed state:

```
+---+---------------+
|img| section title |
+---+---------------+
```

after expansion:

```
+---+---------------+
|img| section title |
+---+---------------+
|                   |
|  section content  |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

When these expand or collapse events occur i'd like to use an interface to notify the observers/listeners/subscribers. In memory should be plenty, no need for a message broker or anything like that.

I'm aware of the Runnable, ActionListener and Observable. Are any one of these the recommended approach or should I create my own. In my application the person listening only needs to know the "String sectionId" assigned to the panel so he can resolve the contents of the panel, which we to populate dynamically.

Would like caller to be able to register for updates with something like this:

```
CollapsibleSection cSection = new CollapsibleSection();
cSection.addListener(MyClass.this);
```

So far I have something like this but want to make sure I'm not always reinventing the wheel so wanted to check with the experts!

```
public interface CollapsibleSectionListener {
    /**
     * @param collapsibleSection
     *            the section that was expanded.
     * @param sectionId
     *            ID of this section that was expanded.
     */
    void onSectionExpand(CollapsibleSection collapsibleSection, String sectionId);

    /**
     * @param collapsibleSection
     *            the section that was collapsed.
     * @param sectionId
     *            ID of this section that was collapsed.
     */
    void onSectionCollapse(CollapsibleSection collapsibleSection, String sectionId);
}
```

Comment: I'm sure to you your question is clear, but to me it is not. Could you please give a specific example of what you want to happen (what is subscribing to what and what would you like to happen?). It'd also help to include what you have tried so far.

Comment: It sounds like you want an event bus - [Guava EventBus](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained) might be useful to you.

Comment: @d.j.brown Updated! Thank you for feedback!

Comment: You "could" use a `PropertyChangeListener`, but I think your `CollapsibleSectionListener` is clearer in it's intention and provides you with the ability to pass specific information about the event.  I'd also consider looking at `EventListener` as a base class for the interface and `EventObject` as a bases for the event object

Comment: @simgineer Thank you, the question is much clearer now. I'd say your approach is good, but obviously you'd need to implement the logic in `CollapisbleSection` to iterate over a `List` of `CollapsibleSectionListener`s and invoke the appropriate methods. Essentially this is what `Observerable` and `Observer` do already, but if you used this library support you would have to implement the logic in your observers in the `update(Observable, Object)` method to query `CollapsibleSection` to determine what has happened, or make use of the `Object` parameter with casting using `notifyObservers(Object)`

Comment: @MadProgrammer If I may will using EventObject and EventListener allow me to use existing list in the source object if it happens to extend a JPanel or is it assumed I will be creating my own list in the source object for this approach as well?

Comment: @simgineer If you implement `EventListener`, you can make use of the `listenerList` defined in `Component` to manager the listener, but that's up to you - it's convent and saves you have to reinvent more wheels